# How to capture the namespace origin from a client side socket.emit serverside socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

If you have a client in a specific namespace/room that performs a socket.emit and you do a "socket on" on the server how can you capture the namespace origin as a string ?

IE:

Client:

```
socket.emit('foo', $('#bar').val());
return false;
```

Server:

```
socket on('foo', function (foo) {
var usersubmitteddata = foo  
var namespaceorigin = ???
});
```

Comment: What do you want namespaceorigin to be set to? `#bar`?

Comment: The user was moved to a namespace when they connected based on IP, specifically;

Comment: Sorry realized the code did not make it in last reply it is :
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  var clientIp = socket.request.connection.remoteAddress;
  socket.join(clientIp);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To list what rooms a socket belongs to just use `socket.rooms`:

```
console.log(socket.rooms);
```

socket.io does not expose which namespace the client connected on, but you can see the current namespace on the server with `socket.nsp.name`, and which exists on the server with `socket.nsp.server.nsps`.

The namespaces that a client should connect to must be created before you connect. If not you will get an `Invalid namespace` error message. But after that it's actually every message that contains the namespace, and not the socket. In the protocol itself you can have a client send messages on different namespaces.

Comment: "socket.io does not expose which namespace the client connected on" Ok confirmed my suspicion. Thank you for taking time to look into this, I really appreciate it.